# How to create an array with duplicates for each element, and test using unit tests? (Java)

Tags: arrays, list, unit-testing

I have created a random array list for a 2x2 matrix for a basic memory game (I'm a beginner).  I'm unsure how to ensure that every value in the array contains a duplicate, and then test it using unit tests.

I thought of adding two arrays together, but this would only work if the random numbers for an array are no greater than the matrix itself (i.e. If you have a 2x2 matrix each array can only generate random numbers from 1-2)
It would be great to have something more robust.

```
public class Board {

final int[][] board = new int[2][2];

public void theList(){
    for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++){
            board[row][col] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
}
}
}

public boolean isMatched(int row, int col){
    return board[row][col] > 0;
}
}
```

I've attached my unit test as well - it runs without errors, but works incorrectly.

```
public class BoardTest {

protected Board mygame;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    mygame = new Board();
}

//Test that cards match
@Test
public void testisMatch(){
    for (int row = 0; row < mygame.board.length; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < mygame.board[row].length; col++);
            if (mygame.board[row] == mygame.board[row]){
            }
    }

}

}
```

Thank you for any help or guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple approach would be to simply generate random integers in pairs, and add them to the board.  You can also do a shuffle at the end if you want the values to be randomly distributed across the board.  Something like this:

```
public class Board {
    private static final int WIDTH = 2;
    private static final int LENGTH = 2;
    private final int[][] board = new int[WIDTH][LENGTH];

    public void theList() {
        List<Integer> vals = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i < WIDTH*LENGTH / 2; ++i) {
            int val = (int)(Math.random()*10);
            vals.add(val);
            vals.add(val);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(vals);
        int i=0;
        for (int row=0; row < board.length; ++row) {
            for (int col=0; col < board[row].length; ++col) {
                board[row][col] = vals.get(i);
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Follow the link below for a **demo** which demonstrates the above logic for a 4x4 game board.  You can see for yourself that every value has a pair, and all values are paired.

## Rextester

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely take it on board - the demo will help a lot! Is there a particular reason you used WIDTH and LENGTH, instead of just int[][] board = new int[2][2]?

Comment: @AVW Yes, in general you want to keep your code as flexible as possible.  If someone sees `2x2` hard coded, they might not know why.  In my version, it is clear what the numbers mean.  You could also consider making the size of the board dynamic.

Comment: @Time Biegeleisen that's interesting, never thought about it like that - makes complete sense though